# Execute stored proc without importing as a function

Tags: .net, sql-server, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

UPDATED:

I want to execute stored proc or sql command which reruns two values.

I was trying to do simple example that using `ExecuteStoreCommand`

First i tried to send just pure sql

```
var sqlReturn = repository.ExecuteStoreCommand("select count(*) as 'Count' FROM 
[mydb].[dbo].[mytable]"); //returns -1
```

but it always returned `-1`.

Then i created stored proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestCount

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select count(*) as 'Count' FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
END
GO
```

But when i called that i get the same `-1` result :

```
var spReturn = repository.ExecuteStoreCommand("exec dbo.TestCount"); //returns -1
```

So is there any way i can do that in Entity Framework without importing anything into model?

The code above just for example, but when i find out how to get the value from sql the query will be much complex, i would need to return count and some another calculated value.

Comment: Don't you need to reference the Count field? Your query and proc are returning a result set and not a returned value.

Comment: @Jeff O question updated

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) method to retrieve values. `ExecuteStoreCommand` will return the number of rows affected. If you execute a Select statement no rows will get affected. Check [How to: Directly Execute Commands Against the Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx) for examples.